# Create Guest Network on both of Two Connected DD-WRT Routers

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, vlan

I have two routers with DD-WRT installed on each.  The first router (**ROUTER A**) (TP-Link ARCHER-C7 v2 running Firmware: DD-WRT v3.0-r41686 std (12/10/19)) is connected to the WAN and is the DHCP server.  The second router (**ROUTER B**) (Belkin F7D3301 DD-WRT v24-sp2 mega) is connected to **ROUTER A** via ethernet to the WAN port, which is set to be a LAN port in DD-WRT (because I needed all five ports for LAN).  **ROUTER B** has WAN disabled and is set to be a DHCP Forwarder, with the Gateway and DHCP server set as **ROUTER A**'s internal IP address.

I want to create a guest network on a separate subnet (e.g., 192.168.**0**.xx for the main network and 192.168.**2**.xx for the guest network) that can be access from users who wirelessly access either **ROUTER A** or **ROUTER B**.  That is, I want both routers to provide wireless access to a main network and a guest network, with (optimally) **ROUTER A** serving the DHCP for both networks (but that is not a requirement).

I have tried to follow the various guides online, but they all seem to use old versions of DD-WRT.

I need help getting this set up, with actual references to the DD-WRT settings (e.g., Basic Setup>Networking>Create Bridge, do this....).

*NOTE: **ROUTER A** and **ROUTER B** currently both have internet access and share it both via ethernet and wifi.  **ROUTER A** also has a working Guest Network on a different subnet, but due to location issues, it is not useful*

Comment: Thanks @Tim_Stewart.  I added them to the question.  They are:  (TP-Link ARCHER-C7 v2 running Firmware: DD-WRT v3.0-r41686 std (12/10/19));  (ROUTER B) (Belkin F7D3301 DD-WRT v24-sp2 mega).  Although not in the original question, I also have a Netgear WNR3500Lv1 on the network running FreshTomato that I would love to have the guest network as well.

Comment: @rsync, What does the TP-Link ARCHER-C7 v2 show you under setup -> subtabs do you have a "switch config" tab there? how about the belkin? devices with Broadcom chip-sets historically support VLANs in dd-wrt. (they were a nightmare to configure on the terminal) if not you may want to update this guys firmware, and see if a switch config tab shows up.

Comment: Yes, there is a 'Switch Config' tab in the Archer.  On the Belkin (also dd-wrt) it is called 'VLAN', but has the same interface.  On the Netgear (Tomato) it is called 'VLAN' tool